# Recuperando o nome de um botao no sender Swift

Tags: swift

Como faço para recuperar o valor de um botão ?

Por exemplo:

Tenho um botão em meu layout com o nome **botaoTeste**, mas quero atribuir o nome desse botão a ser clicado em uma variável!

Isso e possivel?

Obrigado[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhaSu.png)

Comment: Você deve acessar a propriedade `sender.tag`

Comment: Entao o sender.tag eu tenho acesso a tag ai o que eu fiz, eu fiz um array com que eu precisava e quando a tag for igual ao array eu exibo =D

Obrigado!

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta, você poderia marcar ela como correta?

Comment: Troca sender: AnyObject para UIButton e de um print em sender.currentTitle!

Comment: @BrunoBafilli só um detalhe o W vem antes do X no alfabeto e também ta faltando o R no seu keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você pegar o `sender.titleLabel.text`, como ele é um `UIButton` não existe a propriedade `value`

Como seu sender é `AnyObject`, você precisará fazer o cast dele

```
let value = sender.titleLabel.text as! String
```

Caso for usar esse método apenas para botão, aconselho mudar de `AnyObject` para `UIButton`

**Edit**
Você precisa pegar o label do botão (`titleLabel`) e depois pegar o texto (`text`) conforme o exemplo acima

Comment: Não recomende as! String. basta adicionar ! a propriedade text

Comment: Por qual motivo Leo? como o objeto dele é `AnyObject` o próprio `XCode` vai obrigar ele a por pois não vai reconhecer o tipo da propriedade

Comment: O tipo da propriedate text é String? Já o sender sendo AnyObject você deve fazer o cast condicional sender as? UIButton

Comment: Mas nesse caso, usando `as! String` ele esta garantindo que sempre será texto, no contexto da aplicação dele isso é verdadeiro

Comment: Mas o melhor é trocar o sender pra UIButton

Comment: Concordo plenamente :)

Comment: Você tá forçando unwrap as! String. Força direto .text!

Answer (score 2):

Para tal será necessário verificar a propriedade `sender.tag` e utilizar a respectiva para identificar qual botão está sendo disparado.

Comment: Ele também deve trocar o sender type de `AnyObject` pra `UIButton`